# how to fix TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 403 found?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, typeerror, ord

my code is this :

```
print(is_English('Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite'))
print(is_English('Instachat <img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="<img class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">'))

print(ord('™'))
print(ord('<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="<img class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">'))
```

Comment: As the error message said, "ord" expects a single character (precisely: a string of length 1).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, `ord()` only accepts a string representing **one** Unicode character, so the last line in your code will fail since the following is a string of 403 characters:

```
'<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="<img class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">" src="https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11.2.0/svg/1f61c.svg">'
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord